# Outlook Calendar Export Type Issue

Tags: python, pandas, pywin32

I have the following code meant to extract my outlook calendar and show me a list of all participants in the meetings that I have scheduled.. I am running into the following error related to datatypes. I believe the issue is actually getting the events to pull because when I print the appointments list prior to the error, it shows as blank. Thoughts?

Code:

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client

def get_calendar(begin,end):
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application').GetNamespace('MAPI')
    calendar = outlook.getDefaultFolder(9).Items
    calendar.IncludeRecurrences = True
    calendar.Sort('[Start]')
    restriction = "[Start] >= '" + begin.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') + "' AND [END] <= '" + end.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') + "'"
    calendar = calendar.Restrict(restriction)
    return calendar

def get_appointments(calendar,subject_kw = None,exclude_subject_kw = None, body_kw = None):
    if subject_kw == None:
        appointments = [app for app in calendar]    
    else:
        appointments = [app for app in calendar if subject_kw in app.subject]
    if exclude_subject_kw != None:
        appointments = [app for app in appointments if exclude_subject_kw not in app.subject]
    cal_subject = [app.subject for app in appointments]
    cal_start = [app.start for app in appointments]
    cal_end = [app.end for app in appointments]
    cal_body = [app.body for app in appointments]

    df = pd.DataFrame({'subject': cal_subject,
                       'start': cal_start,
                       'end': cal_end,
                       'body': cal_body})
    return df

def make_cpd(appointments):
    appointments['Date'] = appointments['start']
    appointments['Hours'] = (appointments['end'] - appointments['start']).dt.seconds/3600
    appointments.rename(columns={'subject':'Meeting Description'}, inplace = True)
    appointments.drop(['start','end'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
    summary = appointments.groupby('Meeting Description')['Hours'].sum()
    return summary

final = r"C:\Users\rcarmody\Desktop\Python\Accelerators\Outlook Output.xlsx" 

begin = dt.datetime(2021,1,1)
end = dt.datetime(2021,5,12)

print(begin)
print(end)

cal = get_calendar(begin, end)
appointments = get_appointments(cal, subject_kw = 'weekly', exclude_subject_kw = 'Webcast')
result = make_cpd(appointments)

result.to_excel(final)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Python\Accelerators\outlook_meetings.py", line 50, in <module>
    result = make_cpd(appointments)
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Python\Accelerators\outlook_meetings.py", line 34, in make_cpd
    appointments['Hours'] = (appointments['end'] - appointments['start']).dt.seconds/3600
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5461, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
  File "C:\Users\rcarmody\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\accessor.py", line 180, in __get__
    accessor_obj = self._accessor(obj)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\accessors.py", line 494, in __new__
    raise AttributeError("Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values")
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
[Finished in 1.2s]
```

New Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Python\Accelerators\outlook_meetings.py", line 50, in <module>
    result = make_cpd(appointments)
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Python\Accelerators\outlook_meetings.py", line 34, in make_cpd
    appointments['Hours'] = (appointments['end'] - appointments['start']) / pd.Timedelta(hours=1)
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py", line 65, in new_method
    return method(self, other)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\arraylike.py", line 113, in __truediv__
    return self._arith_method(other, operator.truediv)
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4998, in _arith_method
    result = ops.arithmetic_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py", line 185, in arithmetic_op
    res_values = op(lvalues, rvalues)
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\timedeltas.pyx", line 1342, in pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.Timedelta.__rtruediv__
numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'true_divide' cannot use operands with types dtype('float64') and dtype('<m8[ns]')
```

Answer (score 0):

The substraction of two `datetime` objects results in a `timedelta` object. In order to retrieve hours from timedelta objects you can use :

```py
import numpy as np

hours = timedelta_object / np.timedelta64(1, "h")
```

**Note:** it could also be (more pandas-only style)

```
hours = timedelta_object / pd.Timedelta(hours=1)
```

So in your case, you would use it as :

```py
appointments['Hours'] = (appointments['end'] - appointments['start']) / pd.Timedelta(hours=1)
```

Comment: New error posted... looks like a similar issue

Comment: Ok I get it (I think). What does your `appointments["start"]` and `appointments["end"]` look like ? What is their types ? I assumed it was datetime objects but it may not